# Raycast can't hit my player

Tags: unity, physics, raycasting

I have been trying for the past 5 hours to get this to work.

So i have an enemy that has the following script:

```
        private bool Look(StateController controller)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(controller.transform.TransformPoint(controller.mCombatant._CombatOffset),  controller.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 800,
            Color.green);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.SphereCast(controller.transform.TransformPoint(controller.mCombatant._CombatOffset), 360,
                controller.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, 800)
            && hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            controller.mCombatant.Target = hit.transform;
            controller.chaseTarget = hit.transform;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


        return false;
    }
```

Now both my enemy (the one this script is attached to) and my player are on the `default` layer

Here are some images that shows the gameview:

[image]

As you can see from the above picture The "Ray" should hit the player:

My Player prefab looks like this:

[image]

So my question is what have i done wrong?

**EDIT**

So after alot of time i managed to make the following code work (however its a normal raycast :( )

```
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(controller.transform.position, controller.transform.forward, out hit) &&
        hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        var g = 0;
    }
```

This is good but not good enough since i want the vision of my enemy to be more than a straight line :(

Comment: I notice you're using a sphere radius of 360. What led you to choose that number? Can you drop a sphere collider with radius 360 into your scene to see how it compares against the scale of the other objects?

Comment: @DMGregory To be honest nothing made me choose that number it is from several hours of attempts

Answer (score 1):

I think a spherecast radius of 360 is much too big.

Quickly eyeballing your other colliders, it looks like your characters are about 0.4 units in radius themselves, and only a few units apart.

That means when the physics sphere starts its cast, it's already encompassing all of the colliders nearby. Since spherecasts and raycasts detect only stuff they *hit* as they travel, these already-embedded colliders get ignored.

Try reducing your sphere radius to be more on par with the sizes of your characters & scale of their interactions.

Comment: what do you suggest i put in instead then il test those values :)

Comment: "Try reducing your sphere radius to be more on par with the sizes of your characters" ie. 0.4?

Comment: if (Physics.SphereCast(controller.eyes.transform.position, 0.4f,controller.eyes.transform.forward, out hit) &&
                hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                var g = 0;
            }
Still gives me no results :(